# Need help identifying what kind of abelian group this set of points is.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We are given the homomorphisms  $\pi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z/4Z}$ and $f : \mathbb{Z/2Z} \to \mathbb{Z/4Z}$ where $\pi : z \mapsto z+4\mathbb{Z}$ is the natural map and $f:x+2\mathbb{Z} \mapsto2x+4\mathbb{Z}$.

We have to find and identify what group this becomes:

$$X=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z/2Z} | \pi(a)=f(b)\}$$

I've found that $X$ consists of all the pairs in $4 \mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $2+4\mathbb{Z} \times 1+2\mathbb{Z}$.

How do I find which group this is isomorphic to?

Comment: Not an answer, but this is the [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)) of the two maps.

Comment: @SpamIAm: I've looked in some books covering this, it seems like not one of them have anything of a concrete example solved in it. It's just abstract definitions and on to the next topic, and I wonder where people are supposed to learn this stuff from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the elements of $\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$ as $0, 1, 2, 3$. Denote the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as $0,1$.

Now since $f(b)$ can only be $0$ or $2$, and the elements that get sent by $\pi$ in $0$ and $2$ are the ones of the form $4k$ or $4k+2$, you have that $X$ has elements $(4k,0)$ and $(4k+2,1)$.

Now, what is this group isomorphic to...?

Comment: $2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z_2}.$

Comment: Write the explicit map and you are done!